# CSS: navigation bar to expand to the whole page height

Tags: css, height, mockups

Im not too great at CSS but hopefully someone on here can help. I have the following mockup. (i have stripped out my content to make it easy to view)

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
     <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="body">
          <div id="navBar"></div>
          <div id="mainContent"></div>
      </div>
     <div id="footer"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

my CSS is as follows:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

now im unsure as to how to get the "navBar" to be the page height. I've tried adding height: 100% but that doesnt work.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Giving an element `height: 100%` will give it a height equal to that of its *containing element*, which in your case is  `#body`. Since body in your example is only as big as it needs to be to hold its content, `#navBar` will be 100% of *that* height.

To fix this, you can make `#container` and `#body` `height:100%` to make them as tall as tho body tag, which takes up the whole page:

```
#container {
    height:100%
}
#body{
    height:100%;
}
```

In the interest of completeness, you could also set the `top` and `bottom` of `#navBar`:

```
position: absolute; 
top: 20px; 
bottom: 60px; /* height of footer */
```

To understand the difference, play around with [**This JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr4Vz/). Mess around with the `height` and `top, bottom, position` properties to see how your changes affect the layout; just don't use both positioning methods at once!

Comment: I just wanna say to the noobs rejected my changes, that `top;` is an error and `0` is always `0`, doesn't matter the unit of measure you are using. The browser supports both 0 and 0px, because there are noobs like the moderators rejected my changes. So it is, this answer is still broken and I lost precious minutes of my time.

Comment: @dedalo I have updated my answer; please continue to suggest improvements as it's still far from perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be that each parent DIV all the way up to the BODY tag must explicitely have a height of 100% for **#navBar** to have 100% height.  This means you would also have to set the height of **#body** to 100% as well, since it is the parent container of **#navBar**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [site](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) - I assume you want a two column layout - this site will show you how to do what you want.  Hope it helps.